# Inline complex types XSD into a WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I'm currently implementing a web service with a few complex types in java using plain JDK and the integrated web server. Is it possible to tell the JDK to inline the generated XSD for complex types into the WSDL instead of referencing to it via xsd:import?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a neat feature provided by Spring-WS, but I don't think the standard JAX-WS stuff can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use -inlineSchemas in the wsgen tool

(never tried, taken from http://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-85)